# What is the intuition explaining the Shannon-Hartley theorem?

Tags: snr, bandwidth, analog-to-digital, information-theory, capacity

In the digital domain, [the signal to noise ratio (SNR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal-to-noise_ratio) may be interpreted loosely but usefully as *the number of discrete or quantized levels one can transmit reliably*. For instance, loosely speaking, if the maximum input voltage to a circuit channel with with a noise level of $\pm 0.5 V$ is $10 V$ so that the $S/N$ is related to $\frac{10}{1}$ and the maximal number of discrete integer levels one can pass is roughly $11$, which are the integer values of voltage from $0 V$ through $10 V$. The logarithm to the base two simply reflects the number of bits required to transmit this maximum number of levels. This intuition is particularly useful when interpreting [the Shannon-Hartley theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon%E2%80%93Hartley_theorem) represented by $C=B\log_2(1 + S/N)$, wherein the channel capacity $C$ or reliable bit rate is directly proportional to the bandwidth, $B$, and the logarithm of the SNR to the base two. Clearly, $\log_2 (1 + S/N)$ reflects the maximum number of bits one can pass through the channel reliably while $B$ is the rate at which one can pass any number of bits. The interpretation is also corroborated on observing the units of the quantities on the left and right hand side of the equation representing the theorem.

In the analog domain, does the interpretation of the SNR as *the number of discrete or quantized levels one can transmit reliably*, apply readily as in the digital domain, and if not, is there a similar interpretation which provide us the intuition to apply the basic Shannon-Hartley theorem to analog signals?

Edit: Altered text to clarify heuristic interpretation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fundamentally, the signal-to-noise-ratio (SNR or $S/N$) is the ratio of signal power to noise power and that power ratio and is usually expressed in $dB$. Shannon  and Hartley (likely collaborating at Bell labs, 1928) made the connection of the SNR (expressed as the unit-less ratio and not in $dB$) with the bandwidth and capacity a channel has, to (reliably) move data through it.

We shall try to construct a thought experiment that might help illustrate where the Shannon channel capacity theorem might come from. This is nowhere near a rigorous proof and I am making <s>shit</s> things up to help us intuit the likely genesis of the theorem.

---

**Intuition 1:** *Relationship between channel bandwidth and bit-rate capacity*

Suppose your data has high entropy, in that every bit, $d_w$ appears to be independent from every other bit.  At some discrete time, $n$, you can group these bits together into a $W$-bit word of data as an integer, $i[n]$

$$ i[n] = \sum\limits_{w=0}^{W-1} d_w[n] 2^w  $$

here $0 \le i[n] \le 2^W - 1$.  Now suppose we use an ideal $W$-bit Digital-to-Analog converter (DAC) to output a bipolar voltage,

$$x[n] = \Delta \left( i[n] - \frac{2^W - 1}{2} \right)$$

representing data $i[n]$.  We can see that $-\Delta\frac{2^W - 1}{2} \le x[n] \le +\Delta\frac{2^W - 1}{2} $.

Now suppose that DAC output is connected to a $W$-bit Analog-to-Digital converter (ADC) that is scaled exactly (having the same stepsize $\Delta$) as the DAC is so that the analog voltage of $x[n]$ is read exactly correctly by the ADC.  At some discrete time $n$, you have $W$ bits of data $d_w[n]$ that is assembled into a unipolar value $i[n]$, converted into a bipolar DAC voltage of value $x[n]$ that is passed to an ADC that converts the voltage back to the same $W$-bit value $i[n]$, and you have your $W$ bits, $d_w[n]$ back at the other end.  You were able to send these $W$ bits of information across this (so far noiseless) channel to the other end and accurately retrieve the bits.

And in the following discrete sample instance, $n+1$, you can send another $W$ bits, (these bits are $d_w[n+1]$) across the channel and retrieve these bits with your perfectly-scaled ideal ADC.  Now how often can you do that?  If your channel has bandwidth $B$ Hz, then you can send $2B$ samples of $x[n]$ through this channel every second. The sample rate is $2B$.  The ideal DAC output would be:

$$ x(t) = \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} x[n] \operatorname{sinc}\left(2Bt-n \right) $$

where

$$ \operatorname{sinc}(u) \triangleq \begin{cases}
\frac{\sin(\pi u)}{\pi u} \qquad & u \ne 0 \\
1 \qquad & u = 0 \\
\end{cases}$$

That means you're sending $2B\cdot W$ bits of information through this noiseless channel of bandwidth $B$ every second.

---

**Intuition 2:** *Signal power of digital (binary) signal*

Now let's calculate the signal power assuming these bits $d_w[n]$ are totally random and independent of each other.

So assuming the step-size, $\Delta$, of the DAC is uniform the different voltages that the DAC outputs, $x[n]$, are

$$x[n] = \Delta \cdot i[n] - \Delta\frac{2^W - 1}{2},$$

where $i[n]=\sum_{w=0}^{W-1} d_w[n] 2^w$ is some integer $0 \le i[n] \le 2^W - 1$. Since we assume that the bits are uniformly random and independent, then every combination of $W$ bits for the integer word, $i[n]$, from `0000...0000` to `1111...1111` is equally likely.  Therefore, **the signal power which is defined as the expectation of the square of the signal**, is obtained for the signal considered as

$$\begin{align}
 \overline{|x[n]|^2} &= \frac{1}{2^W}\sum\limits_{i=0}^{2^W - 1} \left(\Delta \cdot i -  \Delta\frac{2^W - 1}{2}\right)^2 \\
\\
&= \frac{\Delta^2}{2^W} \left( \sum\limits_{i=0}^{2^{W-1} - 1} \left( i -  \frac{2^W - 1}{2}\right)^2 + \sum\limits_{i=0}^{2^{W-1} - 1} \left(i + 2^{W-1} -  \frac{2^W - 1}{2}\right)^2 \right) \\
\\
&= \ \ \frac{2\Delta^2}{2^W}\sum\limits_{i=0}^{2^{W-1} - 1} (i+\tfrac12)^2 \\
\\
&= \frac{\Delta^2}{2^{W-1}}\sum\limits_{i=0}^{2^{W-1} - 1} (i^2 + i + \tfrac14) \\
\\
&= \frac{\Delta^2}{2^{W-1}} \cdot \left( \frac{(2^{W-1}-1)2^{W-1}(2^W-1)}{6} + \frac{(2^{W-1}-1)2^{W-1}}{2} + 2^{W-1}\tfrac14 \right) \\
\\
&= \Delta^2\cdot\left( \frac{(2^{W-1}-1)(2^W-1)}{6} \ + \ \frac{2^{W-1}-1}{2} \ + \ \frac14 \right) \\
\\
&= \Delta^2\cdot\left( \frac{2^{W-1}2^W - (2^{W-1}+2^W) + 1}{6} \ + \ \frac{2^{W-1}-1}{2} \ + \ \frac14 \right) \\
\\
&= \Delta^2\cdot\left( \frac{2^{2W-1} - 3\cdot2^{W-1} + 1}{6} \ + \ \frac{3\cdot 2^{W-1}-3}{3\cdot2} \ + \ \frac14 \right) \\
\\
&= \Delta^2\cdot\left( \frac{2^{2W-1}-2}{6} \ + \ \frac14 \right) \\
\\
&= \Delta^2\cdot\left( \frac{2^{2W}-4}{12} \ + \ \frac{3}{12} \right) \\
\\
&= \frac{\Delta^2}{12}\cdot(2^{2W}-1).
\end{align}$$

*The expression* above is the signal power or the $S$ in $S/N$.

---

**Intuition 3:** *Relationship between SNR and effective word or pulse width, $W$, which can be passed reliably through the channel*

So far, with the DAC, we're able to transmit $2B$ words of information per second through the channel and each word of information has width $W$ and that many bits of information in it.

Now, how much noise can we add to that signal and still expect the ADC to correctly estimate the value of $x[n]$? In the interest of answering this question simply, in order to illustrate the intuition behind the channel capacity, we make a **big bad** assumption as follows. Shannon assumes noise is (sampled from) a standard Normal or Gaussian random variable with distribution or probability density function (PDF) having variance (power is defined to be the variance) $0<\sigma^2$. However, we assume, purely for mathematical convenience to improve our understanding, that this added noise is uniform PDF of width no bigger than the DAC and ADC step-size $\Delta$.  If we call this channel noise an error signal $\epsilon[n]$ that has uniform probability such that

$$-\frac{\Delta}{2} < \epsilon[n] < \frac{\Delta}{2},$$

then, the signal, $x[n]$ with the noise $\epsilon[n]$ added is

$$y[n] = x[n] + \epsilon[n].$$

We assume that adding that noise $|\epsilon[n]|$ is just barely small enough that this will not cause the ADC to spuriously round to a different word other than $i[n]$ which is transmitted as $x[n]$.  If $\epsilon[n]$ were larger in magnitude, it **could potentially cause the ADC to report a different integer value than $i[n]$ as the output for the input $i[n]$ to the DAC**.

The PDF of $\epsilon[n]$ is

$$ p_\epsilon(u) =  \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{\Delta} \qquad &  |u| < \frac{\Delta}{2} \\
0 \qquad & |u| \ge \frac{\Delta}{2} \\
\end{cases}$$

The **noise power which is defined as the variance or expectation of the squared deviation or mean squared deviation or the squared standard deviation** of a noise signal, is obtained for the noise considered as

$$\overline{|\epsilon[n]|^2} = \frac{\Delta^2}{12},$$

The expression above can be verified from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/728072) post on Stack Exchange which calculates the variance of a random variable with zero mean uniform PDF.

So the SNR is

$$\begin{align}
 \frac{\overline{|x[n]|^2}}{\overline{|\epsilon[n]|^2}} &= \frac{\frac{\Delta^2}{12}\cdot(2^{2W}-1)}{\frac{\Delta^2}{12}} \\
\\
&= 2^{2W}-1 \\
\end{align} $$

Thus, we have a relationship between the number of levels which can be passed reliably through the channel, $W$, or word width  and the SNR given as

$$W = \tfrac12 \log_2 \left(1 + \frac{\overline{|x[n]|^2}}{\overline{|\epsilon[n]|^2}} \right).$$

Further, notice that the effective (that which can be passed reliably through the channel) number of analog (say, voltage) levels is given as

$$2^W = \sqrt{1+SNR},$$

since $W = \frac{1}{2}\log_2 (1+SNR) = \log_2 \sqrt{1+SNR}$.

---

**Shannon-Hartley theorem:** *Maximum channel capacity or theoretical upper bound on net bit or pulse rate is equal to the product of the bandwidth and logarithm to the base 2 of the SNR of the channel*

Based on the intuitive analysis above, we obtain the the (reliable) rate of passage of information or channel capacity as

$$C = 2 B \cdot W = B \log_2 \left(1 + \frac{\overline{|x[n]|^2}}{\overline{|\epsilon[n]|^2}} \right).$$

Comment: This generously contributed answer providing piercing insight is highly appreciated! The text of the original answer was edited by me in order to make it more readable without losing the original flavor of simplicity. Overall, your insightful explanation and conversant analysis corroborates *the intuitive understanding of the SNR as the square root of the effective number number of levels or pulse width or word width which can be (reliably) passed through a channel* as expressed in [the relevant Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon%E2%80%93Hartley_theorem). (1/4)

Comment: If possible, it would be great if you could further clarify in an intuitive manner, via comment or editing the answer, the reasoning supporting the statement 'If your channel has bandwidth $B\; Hz$, then you can send $2B$ samples of $x[n]$ through this channel every second.' in your original answer. (2/4)

Comment: On lightly glossing the contemporary technological circumstance of Shannon, Hartley and the theorem associated with the pair around 1928 CE, it seems that both individuals were working at [Bell labs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_Labs) on repeaters for telegraph signals transmitting Morse code. (3/4)

Comment: The mathematical setting associated with Morse code (which is binary since all Morse code is comprised by place-holders which are dots and dashes) is identical to that of binary or digital signals. This raises the question of how one can apply the fundamental fact in the Shannon-Hartley theorem to the case of purely analog signals, if that thought makes sense. Please consider addressing this issue as a comment or by editing the answer. (4/4)

Comment: Shannon was born in 1916 and graduated from Gaylord MI High School in 1932. So, if he had indeed been collaborating with Hartley at Bell Labs in 1928 as you claim, it would have been when Shannon was 12 years old -- a story that is best taken with a large grain of salt.

Comment: I will edit this to the correct story, if someone will tell it to me.  Or @DilipSarwate, please edit the answer to be historically correct.  I didn't bring up Hartley at all.

Comment: and @kbakshi314, the number of levels is $2^W$, not the word width $W$.  If $W$=16, that means the DAC word is 16-bits but there are $2^W$=65536 DAC levels.

Comment: @DilipSarwate I apologize for the incorrect characterization of Shannon and Hartley having worked together at Bell labs since it seems they did not, based on the timeline. Please allow me to mention that the light reading of the history on which the implication was conditioned, only intended to understand the contemporary technological setting in which the Shannon-Hartley theorem was obtained. Such an understanding can enable intuiting why Shannon, Hartley or Bell labs was concerned with binary signals and it seems plausible that the endeavor is related to the transmission of Morse code.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson we are agreed that the effective (that which can be passed through the channel reliably) number of analog (say, voltage) levels, $2^W$, is not the same as the effective word or pulse width, $W$, although the first comment by me on this answer errs on this understanding. However, the understanding that the effective number of analog levels $2^W=\sqrt{1+SNR}$ conveyed in your answer and other sources such as Wikipedia, has now been added to the answer. If possible, I request you to address the comments above marked (2/4) and (4/4) via comment or editing the answer.

Comment: oh, i'll try to.  i am happy to collaborate on any answer, but at the end of the day, i need to be able to to "own it."

Comment: @kbakshi314 Even a cursory reading of the Wikipedia page that you cite in your question will give you an explanation of what Hartley (and Nyquist) did in the late 1920s and what Hartley gave as an upper bound on the maximum rate of transmission over a channel. The _concept_ of _capacity_ was not developed until the 1940s by Shannon and the $C = B\log_2(1+\text{SNR})$ formula is entirely due to Shannon.

Comment: @DilipSarwate your summary of the associated history is appreciated and we are agreed upon the facts from Wikipedia.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson certainly you own the answer and it is quite insightful. Thanks!

Comment: i know, but i'm gonna have to fix some stuff.  we gotta deal with semantics a little.  like *"SNR"* vs. "$S/N$".  and other stuff.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson please edit per your expertise. I am a controls engineer but am delving into signal processing since I found myself lacking, so notation used by me may easily be problematic. It is great to make your e-acquaintance and continue learning from your understanding. Also, if possible, please clarify the distinction between SNR vs S/N since I thought those notations to be identical (while mentioning units in dB or unit-less).

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson I understood your statement ‘If your channel has bandwidth $B \; Hz$, then you can send $2B$ samples of x[n] through this channel every second. The sample rate is $2B$.’ with the help of a senior colleague. It is Nyquist Sampling theorem in reverse, that is, in order to interpret $B \; Hz$ a $2B \; Hz$ signal (throughput or quality) is required. Thanks so much for this enlightening answer!

Comment: the other thing, @kbakshi314, is that the sinc() function goes through zero at all other sampling instances other than the given sample.  That means no intersymbol interference in this idealized thought experiment.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson I don't understand any of the 'no intersymbol interference in this idealized thought experiment' but that's fine since I'll figure it out at some point. At any rate my goal is to develop the limited understanding of DSP on control implementation. In particular on determining the sampling rates when using closed loop feedback which may be using some sort of model predictive feed-forward including complex look-up such as MPC or ANN. I'll post a question on that topic soon and hope to invite you to respond!

Answer (score 4):

Echoing what already answered: you are approaching this backwards. SNR is a concept that's very fundamental and applicable to way more things that just channel capacity.

If you have a signal $y(t)$ that's the sum of a desired signal $x(t)$ and a noise signal $r(t)$ , i.e. $y(t) = x(t) + r(t)$ the SNR in dB is simply

$$ SNR_\mathrm{dB} = 10 \cdot \log_{10} \frac{\langle x^2 \rangle}{\langle r^2 \rangle}$$ where $\langle \cdot \rangle$ is the mean value operator.

Note that this a power ratio. There no assumption whatsoever about spectral, temporal or amplitude distribution of the noise (or the desired signal). I SOME cases the SNR can indeed be used to estimate the channel capacity. The Shannon channel capacity explicitly assumes that the it's additive white Gaussian noise (AWGN) channel. I.e. the noise is spectrally white, has a Gaussian amplitude distribution and is stationary in time. For different type of noises, things are are different and the simple formula does not hold any more.

> if the maximum input voltage to a circuit channel with with noise of $\pm 0.5 V$ is $10 V$ or $SNR=\frac{10}{1}$

That's not a useful way to think about it. First of all you need to specify whether your numbers are peak or RMS (i.e. root mean square) values. The definition of SNR uses RMS, however your argument uses peak value. For Gaussian noise, individual samples or instances of the noise can be much larger than the RMS and there is no easy way to even define a Peak value. Hence it requires a statistical argument.

Comment: Actually, Hil, the Shannon channel capacity theorem can be generalized for non-white signal and noise: 

$$ C = \int\limits_{0}^{B} \log_2\left( 1 + \frac{S(f)}{N(f)} \right) \ \mathrm{d}f $$

Comment: Thanks for the answer and comment. However the question intends to understand the intuition behind the proportional relationship between channel capacity and $B\log_2 (1+SNR)$. Heuristic approximation of the number of levels one can pass reliability under an uncertainty of $\pm 5V$ is indeed $11$ in the case of maximum signal voltage of $10V$ implying $\log_211$ bits that can be passed. I request any comments or answers relating to the basic heuristic.

Comment: *//"he question intends to understand the intuition behind the proportional relationship between channel capacity and $B\log_2(1+SNR)$"//*  ---------  So you want someone to tell you how the Shannon-Hartley equation for channel capacity is derived?  That's a tall order.  I might be able to think up a specific example thought experiment that will hint to the intuition.  With a DAC and an ADC, but it's not gonna be easy.

Comment: A specific example thought experiment goes a long way to build intuition and such an answer is welcome. I agree that explaining the theorem in an intuitive manner is non-trivial, which is in fact the goal of the question.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: true, but I think this still assume "stationary" noise. If you have noise that's has a time pattern to it, this probably wouldn't work.

Comment: @Hilmar, the assumption is stationary, but the real fictitious assumption is that the additive noise is uniform p.d.f.  I'll try to put together this "thought experiment".  It was an end-of-chapter problem in one of my textbooks and I remembered it as instructive.

Comment: @kbakshi314, hang on.  i'll try to do that.